# Change color of object in Photoshop CS

Tags: photoshop

I have a image I am editing in photoshop CS, I want to replace the black color of an object with blue, I've done this in the past but for some reason the Contrast/brightness tool is not working, I can change the brightness but the object is just staying black. I tried using the magic wand and selecting the object and then fillinf it but that leaves uneven edges.

Comment: This question is not related to programming. Make sure to ask on the appropriate forums.

Comment: photoshop is a tag on this forum.

Comment: An irrelevant observation. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic (although some developers may argue that Photoshop is a "software tool" they use often, such is a dubious claim for this being an appropriate place to ask question on it's usage)

Comment: also photoshop can be used in several ways - programatically or to edit meta information to be extracted via PHP for example. therefore there is a tag. your question is just totally unrelated to that scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Just select the background with one of the selecting tools, make selection bigger and then CTRL U, when try a blur around the edges?